# Responsividade diferente entre navegadores (Webkit & Mozilla)

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo, firefox, webkit

Uso Bootstrap 3 no meu projeto. Usei o Mozilla durante todo o processo de criação, e o design responsivo funciona muito bem nele e no Edge. Quando fui testar as páginas em navegadores que usam WebKit (Chrome e Safari), elas aparecem bem diferente do que eu havia visto no Mozilla.

Parece que uma mesma resolução ativa a classe `.sm` no Mozilla, porém permanece no `.md` no Webkit. Abaixo uma comparação da mesma página em dois navegadores.

[image: Imagens webkit e mozilla]
À esquerda: **Chrome**. À direita: **Mozilla Firefox**.

Percebam que no Chrome, a navbar nem chegou ao ponto de esconder os links e exibir um menu hamburguer.

Como posso resolver isso?
Obrigado.

Comment: Diga-me, está seguindo isso aqui: [Basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda Opa cara, acertou em cheio! Faltava a linha `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` no meu código. Você pode escrever uma resposta nesse post para eu marcar como respondido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta tag `viewport`. Ela dá ao navegador informações sobre como controlar as dimensões da página independentemente do navegador (ou dispositivo utilizado).

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Fonte: [Basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template); [Setting The Viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).