# Bootstrap: Responsivo não funciona com site hospedado

Tags: bootstrap, hospedagem, layout-responsivo

Eu estou fazendo um tcc para o meu curso técnico e como um dos quesitos era fazer um site responsivo, resolvi usar o bootstrap, porém, quando eu hospedei o site, ele apresentou alguns problemas.

Quando eu abro o meu site no celular, de forma local, como nas imagem abaixo, ele funciona normalmente a parte responsiva.

[image]
[image]

Quando eu abro ele no local, ele fica como na imagem abaixo.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image]

Comment: Confere que tem essa tag no seu site <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser [o mesmo problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174735/responsividade-diferente-entre-navegadores-webkit-mozilla) que eu encontrei no meu TCC meses atrás. Você pode colocou essas três tags no seu head (atenção especial para a `viewport`)?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
...
</head>
```

Comment: Muto Obrigado, coloquei e deu certo!